# AmCharts Map - get List of all selected countries

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

i'm creating an angular project using the amcharts world map.

as you can see in this demo: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/selecting-multiple-areas-map/#code

we can select multiple countries, can someone guide me here and tell me where i can find all the selected countries (the list containing the countries names or their codes) ???

```
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target);
});
```

Comment: polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("click", function(ev) {
         console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext); 
        });

Comment: i want to get the list of active countries that i have clicked on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but you can do something like that

```
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.each(p => {
    if(p.isActive){
        //...your code...
    }
  })
```